# Mongo-what is the difference between session.getDatabase vs db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongo-shell

What is the difference between `session.getDatabase("examples").getCollection("data").find().noCursorTimeout()`,
`db.data.find().noCursorTimeout()`? I m planning on using noCursorTimeout with refresh session but I would like to know which one among the above commands work for my use case.

Use case:
I have a huge collection with enormous amount of data and it is timing out at certain point on my cursor query with an error `"codeName" : "CursorNotFound", "errmsg" : "cursor id <xyz> not found"`if I don't use noCursorTimeout. So I m planning on using it with refreshing the session similar to [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.noCursorTimeout/#cursor.noCursorTimeout)
So my question is as I m refreshing the session do I need to use the session.getDatabase cursor or else as I will be logged in to mongo db I can directly use db.collection cursor and I m also confused cause as soon as I login to mongo db will there be a startSession and it has its own session id and by using db.collection it will not refresh the logged in session